# Why doesn't the emulator start even though the build was successful?

Tags: ios, xamarin, build, xamarin.ios, emulation

Good day, dear developers, I have a Xamarin application (IOS, Android). Earlier the emulator started normally, but this time for some reason it didn't. All projects were assembled successfully, but the emulator did not start. I don't understand why. Help me please.
If you need additional information - write

Console(Build)

```
========== Build: Successful - 1, Failed - 0, Up-to-Date - 3, Skipped - 0 ==========
========== 00:26,404 elapsed ==========
========== Deployment: success - 0, failure - 0, skip - 0 ==========
========== 00:26,404 elapsed ==========
```

[debugging options for the IOS project]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SozV.png

Answer (score 0):

- Since it worked before, rather than trying to figure out what internally is messed up (something in VS, something in emulator, communication between VS and emulator), easiest fix is to **reboot computer**.
- If that doesn't do it, exit VS, **delete all .bin and .obj folders** in solution.
- If still messed up, exit VS, **delete solution's hidden .vs folder**. (Are you on Mac? Not sure if it uses a different technique to store settings.)
- If it were an Android emulator, I'd consider **Factory Reset**, but I've never had to do that on an iOS simulator.